# Merge new react native app into an existing one

Tags: react-native

I have an existing React Native app deployed to the iOS and Android app stores.

Now, we have a new React Native app that we would like to integrate as a view within the existing app. Unfortunately the React Native app version and dependencies are completely different as compared to the existing app.

Is there any way that the new app can be integrated into the existing one?

Ideally I'd want to use the existing app as is and have a button within it where upon clicking, the new app's views could be shown to the user.

On searching online, there is a lot of documentation about integrating a React Native app into an existing native Android or native iOS app, but nothing about into an existing React Native app. Eg: https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance